# Subscribe возвращает строку Angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular2

Есть запрос к серверу:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

sendRequest(data) {

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache' 
    });
    const headersObject = {
        headers: headers
    }

    const body = {
        prop: value
    };
    return this.http.post('url', body, headersObject).subcribe(e => e)
}
```

Почему subscribe вместо Observable возвращает строку, которую невозможно распарсить  json() или JSON(parse) ?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77529/discussion-on-question-by-alexeev-subscribe---angular2).

Comment: возвращает строку, потому что вы пишете subscribe, уберите subscribe, тогда и будет возвращать Observable

Comment: Но мне же нужно данные из  Observable считать. Получилось только так JSON.parse(res.toString()

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вы данные получите, а уже откуда метод вызываете используете subscribe.

```
return this.http.post('url', body, headersObject).map((response: Response) => response.json());
```

Comment: начиная с 4.3 HttpClient сам делает вызов `.json()`